# Some characters in stopwords_tr do not appear Turkish character

Tags: r, replace, gsub, stop-words

```
stopwords_tr <- data.frame(word = stopwords::stopwords("tr",source="stopwords-iso"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
stopwords_tr
```

Some characters in stopwords_tr are not in Turkish. For example;

```
1   acaba
2   acep
3   adamakıllı
4   adeta
5   ait
6   altmýþ   <-Here must be: altmış
7   altmış
8   altý     <-Here must be: altı
```

I'm looking for a way to fix them.

```
stopwords_tr$word<-gsub("ý","ı",stopwords_tr$word)
```

The result has not changed.
I tried these, but it didn't.

```
Encoding (stopwords_tr $ word) <- "WINDOWS-1254"
Encoding (stopwords_tr $ word) <- "LATIN-5"
Encoding (stopwords_tr $ word) <- "UTF-8"
```

Another interesting thing.

When you double-click `stopwords_tr` in R Studio to display it, the character appears `"ý"`. In Console, it looks like `"y"`.

Is there a parameter to set encoding?
Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed #user2554330's advice. However, I applied to a different address than the address he showed.
I contacted the creator of stopwords-tr (Kenneth Benoit). The problem stems from a mis-encoded data source. I also noticed repetitive words and reported them. Together we solved the character problem. stopwords-tr was updated. In the following address;

(Fix Turkish #16)

https://github.com/quanteda/stopwords/pull/16

```
devtools::install_github("quanteda/stopwords", ref = "fix-tr")

stopwords("tr", source = "stopwords-iso")
```

"Turkish Stopwords" now seems to be properly encoded. 
Greetings..

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure this is an error, I think the best way to fix this is to fix the original source:  post an issue to https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-iso/issues or https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-tr/issues (not sure which is better; try one, and if you get it wrong, they'll tell you!)

But check that it really is wrong.  I don't know Turkish, but when I do a Google search for "altmýþ", I find it on several pages that look like Turkish to me, e.g. https://greatsong.net/PAROLES-ISMAIL-YK,ISTEMIYORUM-SENI,101646494.html.  Probably an encoding error, but if it is a common one, maybe you really do want it in the list.

Regarding the display issues:  sounds like you're on Windows.  R on Windows has issues displaying non-native characters.  You probably don't have Icelandic installed, so it will have trouble displaying a word like altmýþ.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I'm solving character problems for R by typing the following code. Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "turkish"). The site of the stopwords for R is different from what you say. Following your recommendation, I've added it to https://github.com/quanteda/stopwords/issues/15. Thanks #user2554330.